# user rights to /usr/share

Tags: installing

My question concerns this statement in Tex Live Quick Install:

"... we recommend installing it as a normal user... Of course, you need to have permission to write into the destination directory, but TeX Live itself does not care if you are root or not."

I assume this refers to the directory /usr/share. Should I chmod that directory and grant write privileges to the user who will install Tex Live? A specific linux command would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Either install as root, or make a folder somewhere else install there and add this new path to your system PATH, never manually mess with permissions under `/usr`. I personally have latex installed in `/opt/texlive/<year>` and `/opt/texlive` is owned by my user. Then I don't need sudo to update.

Comment: Usually TeX Live installs in `/usr/local/texlive` and subdirectories thereof, unless it is packaged by some GNU/Linux distribution. ***Don't*** use `/usr/share` yourself.

Comment: Installing as a normal user means installing it (somewhere) in your `$HOME`  directory.

Comment: I ran "perl install-tl -gui" as a normal user from that user's home. It attempted to do the install of Tex Live into /usr/local/texlive/2019 but aborted because permissions were not set correctly. So my original question should have said /usr/local instead of /usr/share. But I still need to know how to set rights to do this installl as a user. In the past, I've always just used sudo, but have recently experienced some strangeness in use of various fonts. So I'm trying to fix that problem doing the installation as a "regular" user (me). Thanks.